# icons image are missing on dock panel

Tags: virtualbox, icons, panel, dock

I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS and then I have installed virtualbox but when I open some VM, icons  do not show up on the dock panel:
[image: dock]
I have installed a custom shell and its icon is missing too.
What can I do?

edit_
somebody told me I had to give more info:
well, I guessed that image I uploaded will express all.
On that screen im running two VMs, Ubuntu and Debian
if you glance to the right of the image you could see 2 black icons .
well, everytime I open a virtual machine, their icons on the dash panel do not appear. That problem did not occur when I did use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version
sorry for my bad english, not native speaker.

Comment: Which icons are missing? In order to help you, we need to know more. You should provide use with as much information as possible. Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1247939/edit) to update your question

Comment: Same for me, When I started my Windows VM the icon is missing but if my Ubuntu 20 goes to sleep and then wakes up the VM icon is right there.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18705

Answer (score 3):

Here is a temporary solution: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. GNOME Shell will restart and the logo will appear.